# stringstreams and formatting

Tags: c++, string-formatting, stringstream

I am using C++ and writing a program that is supposed to do a bunch of stuff with primes. However the main issue is that I am having trouble converting in between ints and strings. I believe the following is the relevant code:

```
for(int j=0;j<size-1;j++){
  num=primes[j];
  ss<<num;
  ss>>temp;
  ss.str("");
  for (int count=0; count < temp.size(); count++) {
      cout<<temp<<endl;
  }
```

I know that I could Google and figure out how to convert from an integer another way. However, I have a feeling that the reason I can't figure out what is going wrong is because I'm lacking some fundamental knowledge about stringstreams which I'm not aware of which I'm hoping can be fixed. `num` is an int and `ss` is a stringstream and `cout temp` is printing out 2 every single time, which is the value of `primes[0]`. I think the stringstream might be not reading after the first trial because of something to do with a newline character but I don't really know.

Comment: Yes I received my first upvote! Why would I receive it so long after I actually posted the question though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for what you are experiencing is that the EOF_BIT will be set in `ss` after reading the first value into `temp`, after that no read/writes can be made to the `std::stringstream` and therefore `temp` is not updated with a new value.

A more human readable way of explaining the above; the std::stringstream `ss` will think that it has reached the end (which it has, at one point). You'll need to tell it to "start all over again" (reset all error-flags) for it to be usable in another iteration.

---

#### How do I solve this issue?

There are a few methods available, to me the most clear (in code readability) is to use a new `std::stringstream` for each iterator in your loop (see "**Example solution #2**).

Check out the snippets below that all will output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
```

---

#### Example solution #1

```
  int const PRIMES_SIZE         = 7;
  int const primes[PRIMES_SIZE] = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17};

  std::stringstream ss; 
  std::string temp;

  for (int i =0; i < PRIMES_SIZE; ++i) {
    ss << primes[i];
    ss >> temp;

    std::cout << temp << std::endl;

    ss.clear (); // unset error flags
  }
```

---

#### Example solution #2

```
  int const PRIMES_SIZE         = 7;
  int const primes[PRIMES_SIZE] = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17};

  for (int i =0; i < PRIMES_SIZE; ++i) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << primes[i];

    std::cout << ss.str () << std::endl;
  }
```

---

#### Example solution #3

```
  #include <iterator>

  ...

  int const PRIMES_SIZE         = 7;
  int const primes[PRIMES_SIZE] = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17};

  std::stringstream ss;

  std::copy (primes, primes+PRIMES_SIZE, std::ostream_iterator<int> (ss, "\n"));

  std::cout << ss.str ();
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Also is it necessary to have the ss.str("") after each read in, or does the ss discard the data when you extract from it?

Comment: @emschorsch it's not required, read data will be "removed" from the stringstream.

Comment: Thanks, also is it not a waste of space or something to create a new stringstream each time, or is it standard practice?

Comment: @emschorsch if you are talking memory allocation it won't be any problems, though creating a new stringstream might create *some* overhead, but usually this isn't anything you'll need to worry about. The bottle-neck of your application is probably elsewhere.